# How can I save form data in ASP.NET MVC using Ajax without refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to save form data in ASP.NET MVC using Ajax without refresh. I tried two days long but still it not works. I did it using web method but that does not work in ASP.NET MVC.

Ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#saveDepartmentForm").submit(function () {
            var dept = {};
            dept.DepartmentCode = ("#departmentCode").val();
            dept.DepartmentName = ("#departmentName").val();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "SaveDepartment/SaveDept",
                    data: { aDepartment: dept },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("User has been added successfully.");

                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }

                });

            });

       });
</script>
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult SaveDepartment()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDept(Department aDepartment)
{
    return Json(aSaveDepartmentManager.SaveDepartment(aDepartment));
}
```

Department class:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add your department class

Comment: what error do u have get?

Comment: department class added. data not save in database

Comment: Please share savedepartment method.

Comment: Very simple solution :  

Your controller name is  "SaveDepartment" and you had written the action method with same name. This is wrong. This not allowing you to build your solution and gives followinng error :

Error :  Error CS0542 'SaveDepartmentController': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type 
Example : 
// This is your mistake if i am correct
public ActionResult SaveDepartment()
{
    return View();
}

Comment: Please try this and let me know

Comment: When you submit a form it posts to an action and then loads that action's view. If you're wanting to use ajax like a SPA, then you need to preventDefault on the form submit or just use a click handler on a button and post without the form submit action. Also, make sure you're actually posting data by serializing your form data for you ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I save form data in ASP.NET MVC using Ajax without refresh

It appears you are catching the form submit via

```
 $("#saveDepartmentForm").submit()
```

However you need to cancel the submit in order for your page not to refresh:

```
 $("#saveDepartmentForm").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // ... the rest of your code.
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution and I will provide a draft for it.

1. Send you data via `$.ajax` **POST**.
2. Your controller should return some value back to make sure that the POST passed well.
3. As soon as you get passed value you can reload exactly the part of DOM you need or do nothing.

Check my code that explain it. (Sorry cannt use your code.)

**1.** Send you data via $.ajax POST.

`// Prepare your input parameters
    let params = { dcBuilderID: dcbuilderid, stockID: $('#selectedStockItem').data('stockid'), quantity: $('#stockQuantity').val() };`

```
$.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("AddDCBuilderDetail", "DCBuilder")', data: params, method: 'PUT',
   }).fail(function () {
     // console.log('Error');
   }).done(function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      if (data.success === true) {
       // Here you do nothing or update DOM
      }
      else {
        // console.log('Error');
      }
 });
```

**2.** Your controller should return some value back to make sure that the POST passed well.

[HttpPut]
public ActionResult AddDCBuilderDetail(Guid dcBuilderID, Guid stockID, int quantity)
{
  var result = false;
  var message = string.Empty;

  try
  {
    result = repoDCBuilder.AddNode(dcBuilderID, stockID, quantity);
    if (!result)
    {
       message = MessageHelper.ErrorSaveData;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logger.Error(ex);
    return Json(new { success = result, msg = ex.Message }, 
     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

return Json(new { success = result, msg = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

**3.** As soon as you get passed value you can reload exactly the part of DOM you need or do nothing.

Look at the #1 and read here

```
if (data.success === true) {
    // Here you do nothing or update DOM
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change your `$.ajax()` to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/SaveDepartment/SaveDept",
    data: dept,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("User has been added successfully.");
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

> check out these  [demos](https://github.com/irshadahmedevs/eVentureSolutionCodeBank-ASP.Net-/tree/master/AjaxImplementationDemos) so you will get more understanding of ajax work
>   flow